# question on risk reversal P/L example in Euan Sinclair's book 'positional option trading'

Tags: implied-volatility, option-strategies, skewness

I am reading Euan's book, ‘positional option trading’ and have a question about risk reversal P/L example. Here is description 'Consider a 1-month risk reversal on a \$100 stock. The 20-delta put (91 strike) has an implied volatility of 40.8% and the 20-delta call has an implied volatility of 23.1%. We sell the put and buy the call because we expect the skew to flatten. Table 8.11 shows the profits we make on the position for various degrees of flattening. However, the expected daily move of a \$100 stock with a volatility of 30% is \$1.50. If the stock drops to \$98.5, the risk reversal loses \$94,  and if the stock rallies to \$101.5,the risk reversal will make $16. So, an average daily P/L due to the stock's random fluctuations is \$55. '

I wonder how the author came up with these numbers(ie, \$94 loss, \$16 make, daily P/L due to stock move \$55). I can figure out here risk reversal through selling 20-delta put(compute put strike at 91 with volality=iv of 40.8%) and long 20-delta call(compute call strike at 103 with volatilty=iv 23.1%). I know the P/L(-94, +16, +55) here due to delta/gamma effect, I believe delta is 0.4(0.2+0.2, correct me if I am wrong), tried to use all kinds of ways(including ATM volatility(0.3) and implied volatilities, etc) to compute the P/L due to stock move, but I couldn't get the numbers here. Can anyone help me out? Thanks very much in advance!

Fred